# Mixins in faultCode in SOAP response

Tags: java, xml, soap, spring-ws

Hello stackoverflow users!
I have fault response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001">
         <faultcode>ns0:B-NONUNIQUE-WORKORDERID</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Work order ID is not unique</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Fault code has a mixin "ns:0" but I need fault code without it like this:

```
<faultcode>B-NONUNIQUE-WORKORDERID</faultcode>
```

My java custom fault implementation in spring ws exception resolver:

```
public class OssNinasExceptionResolver extends SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver implements InitializingBean {

private static final String SCHEMA_URL = "{http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001}";

protected SoapFaultDefinition getFaultDefinition(Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
        SoapFaultDefinition fault = new SoapFaultDefinition();
        fault.setLocale(null);
        final Throwable rootcause = rootCauseExtractor.extractRootCause(ex);
        if (rootcause instanceof RequestValidationException) {
            RequestValidationException requestValidationException = (RequestValidationException) rootcause;
            fault.setFaultCode(QName.valueOf(SCHEMA_URL + requestValidationException.getCode()));
            fault.setFaultStringOrReason(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(requestValidationException.getDescription(), GENERAL_ERROR));
            return fault;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {
        Throwable rootCause = rootCauseExtractor.extractRootCause(ex);
        if (rootCause instanceof RequestValidationException) {
            String code = ((RequestValidationException) rootCause).getCode();
            BaseErrorType errorDetails = createValidationErrorDetails(code, rootCause.getMessage());
            final SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = fault.addFaultDetail();
            final Result result = faultDetail.getResult();
            try {
                jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(errorDetails, result);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                LOG.info(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Debug session showed that this mixin doesn't appear while processing in exception resolver. 
Any hints show to make this thing disappear?

Answer (score 0):

`ns0` is a namespace prefix (There is no such concept as "mixin" anywhere in the XML specs). In the scope of the `faultcode` element, that namespace prefix is bound to the namespace URI `http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001`. This means that the fault code has namespace URI `http://xmlns.telenet.be/oss/ninas/v001` and local part `B-NONUNIQUE-WORKORDERID`, which is exactly what you request in your code:

```
fault.setFaultCode(QName.valueOf(SCHEMA_URL + requestValidationException.getCode()))
```

Comment: Everything exactly as you said but when I try to create a fault code without url it throws an exception, the question is still open: how to get rid of namespace prefix in fault code?

Comment: What does the exception say? That fault codes without namespace are not allowed (see http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#R1004)?

Comment: Thanks for the link it was quite useful argument in chat with my PM, but anyway are there any ways to get rid of this prefix?

Comment: You would have to unwrap the message to access the underlying SAAJ (or Axiom) message and use that API to set the fault code (as text instead of QName, to avoid any conformance checks).